# Replace corrupted spyder.ini file (with winpython 64)

Tags: python, spyder

I'm working with WinPython and Spyder, and somehow spyder wouldn't start. It would briefly flash an error message of which the relevant line is: `ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: D:\progs\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\settings\.spyder\spyder.ini  [line 431]: u'_/switch to'`.

Then delving into that file it seems to be clipped. It abruptly ends on line 431 with `_/switch to` in the `[shortcuts]` section of the file.

Can anyone link me to a complete spyder.ini file, I can't find it in the spyder github? Or if it's the last line (or one of the last few lines), provide me with the bit I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply removing the line which was an issue and starting Spyder did the trick. Spyder rebuilt the spyder.ini file upon running spyder.exe.